# Orchestration for a simple server in C

Tags: c, sockets, server, queue, pthreads

I'm trying to make a simple multi-thread server in C, and I would like to make a queue for clients, so no one drops connection.
But I have no idea what to do and where to start.
Anyone can help? Any advices would be appreciated :)

and I had to remove the thread function code because code was too long that this question won't post.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket; //long valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    pthread_t tid[1024];
    int i = 0; // index for tid array
    
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("In socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    
    memset(address.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof address.sin_zero);
    
    
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("In bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if (listen(server_fd, 10) < 0)
    {
        perror("In listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n+++++++ Waiting for new connection ++++++++\n\n");
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("In accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        if( pthread_create(&tid[i++], NULL, thread, &new_socket) != 0 )
            printf("Failed to create thread\n");
        
        if( i >= 1024 )
            i = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is best achieved with a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) pattern. Each working thread will "grab" the next pending connection once it finished with the previous one.

Comment: 'pthread_create(&tid[i++], NULL, thread, &new_socket)' - unreliable.  'new_socket' may be overwitten before the client handler thread can dereference the pointer.

Comment: "I would like to make a queue for clients, so no one drops connection" -- This should normally not be necessary. It should generally be sufficient to set the second argument of [`listen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/listen.3p.html) to a sufficiently high value.